# ActiveReports: Failed to add the custom paper size

Tags: printing, activereports

I have a desktop computer with a tiquet printer on my network.

On the server side, I print with this the tiquet generated after some user interaction with a web application.

The main problem comes when I try to set PaperKind.Custom. This error raises:

> Failed to add the custom paper size to the printer ARCustomForm, System error number: 5

If I don't set PaperKind.Custom it works, but it doesn't know the height of the ticket so it takes out a blank piece.

This is the code:

```
srParte report = new srParte(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(), "Test", 15.0f, "Cola");
report.PageSettings.PaperKind = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.Custom;
report.PageSettings.PaperWidth = 2.75f;
report.PageSettings.PaperHeight = 3.2f;
report.PageSettings.Margins = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.Section.Margins(0f, 0f, 0.3f, 0f);
var printer = @"\\192.168.33.235\NII ExD NP-3511";
report.Document.Printer.PrinterName = printer;
report.Run();

report.Document.Print(false, false, false);
```

If I put the server on the computer that has the printer, this code works perfect, but the server doesn't have to be on this pc.

I found this, but there is not information on how to solve this: https://dev.grapecity.co.jp/support/kb/detail.asp?id=27251

Answer (score 0):

Lechucico,

"Failed to add the custom size ...." error occurs when the paper size set in Section report does not support by the installed printer. So, you need to set the paper size of section report which is supported by installed printer at your end. Else, You need to set to set the paper size to the printer default through the different printers as all printers support different sizes. Please set the "DefaultPaperSize" property of section report to 'True'. Please use the following line of code:

rpt.PageSettings.DefaultPaperSize = True

Thanks.